# Java Print a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, printing

I hope you can help. I'm trying to print a JFrame in java. It doesn't necessarily need to be the whole JFrame, Only a small area where I'll add text and an image. If i can get the JLabel to print that should be a good start. I need it to print when the user performs an action in the text field(action performed) not when a user clicks print like in other code (PrintUIWindow).

I found some code online(PrintUIWindow) which I tried to put into my code with no luck. The code works but i just don't understand where to put it in regards to a jframe.

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now print the window and its visible contents */
    frameToPrint.printAll(g);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

I would then put the below in the action performed

```
 PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {
          /* The job did not successfully complete */
         }
     }
```

Attached is the bare bones of my code. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with my code.

```
package javaapplication42;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.print;
import static sun.misc.Version.print;
import static sun.misc.Version.print;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable, ActionListener {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();


}

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pagenum) {

   if (pagenum > 0){
       return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
   }

   g.translate((int)format.getImageableX(), (int)format.getImageableY());

   float pageWidth = (float)format.getImageableWidth();
   float pageHeight = (float)format.getImageableHeight();

   float imageHeight = (float)this.getHeight();
   float imageWidth = (float)this.getWidth();

   float scaleFactor = Math.min((float)pageWidth/(float)imageWidth, (float)pageHeight/(float)imageHeight);

   int scaledWidth = (int)(((float)imageWidth)*scaleFactor);

   int scaledHeight = (int)(((float)imageHeight)*scaleFactor);  

   BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage( this.getWidth(),  this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics2D gg = canvas.createGraphics();
   this.paint( gg );  
   Image img = canvas ;

   g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null );

   return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("TEXT TO PRINT");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addContainerGap(316, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(218, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     /* The job did not successfully complete 
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
 job.setPrintable(this);
 boolean ok = job.printDialog();
 if (ok) {
     try {
          job.print();
     } catch (PrinterException ex) {

     }
 }
 */

     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PageFormat format = job.defaultPage();
    format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    job.setPrintable(this, format);

    try{
        if(job.printDialog()) job.print();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}




}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


}
```

Hopefully there isn't too much code, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly?  Your code already has an `actionPerformed` method and a `print` method.  You just need to put that code you found into those methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried and a blank piece of paper printed off :(

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code you tried.

Comment: For [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728397/print-the-whole-program-layout/16728708#16728708), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22242658#22242658), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450012/using-printerjob-to-print-an-image-graphics2d/14450329#14450329),

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22244116#22244116), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070689/printing-a-2-pages-of-jframe-in-java/29137211#29137211), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904518/fit-scale-jcomponent-to-page-being-printed/17961911#17961911)

Comment: Thanks I managed to get this sorted. I will edit my code to show the solution. I'd now like to offset the X and Y axis so i am not printing the whole Jframe but i'll ask another question.